# why apache server redicect /doc to usr/share/doc

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ubuntu

I have the rewrite ruls in .htaccess file under /var/www in my ubuntu10.4 server like below, When the url appears to be http://127.0.0.1/doc/view, the webpage shows "The requested URL /doc/view was not found on this server", and then I check the apach log, it logs "File does not exist: /usr/share/doc/view", so apprently apache redirect the /doc/view to /usr/share/doc/view. I don't know what it is going on here, can anybody help? thanks for help.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apache's default config on many distributions makes it so you can go to `http://localhost/doc/`to read the Apache documentation. You can edit this out in your `httpd.conf` or `apache2.conf` file if you need to use `/doc` for your own URLs.

Comment: ok, thanks, that is what I thought in the first place, but there isn't anything like /doc redirection in apache2.conf file. and the httpd.conf is blank.

Comment: Try looking in `sites-available/default` for `Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"`.

Comment: oh,,,yes, there it is,,you are the best.

Comment: Glad I could help ya out. :-)